# SQL works however the prepared statement does not

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

My prepared statement is producing the following error in the log "SQLException in getVenturerSectDtls: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'kilometres' not found.

The prepared statement is:

```
    String selectQry = ("SELECT cdID, surname, firstName, dob, archived, scoutNo, grpName, startDate, endDate, SUM(kilometres), SUM(nights) from ( " +
            "SELECT at_cub_details.cd_id as cdID, at_cub_details.cd_surname as surname, at_cub_details.cd_first_name as firstName," +
                " at_cub_details.cd_dob as dob, at_cub_details.cd_archived as archived, at_cub_details.cd_scout_no as scoutNo, " +
                " at_group.grp_name as grpName, " +
                " at_section_details.sd_start_date as startDate, at_section_details.sd_end_date as endDate, " +
                " null as kilometres, null as nights " +
            " FROM at_cub_details, at_account_group, at_group, at_section_details " + 
            " WHERE at_account_group.acc_id = ? " + 
                " AND at_account_group.grp_id = at_cub_details.grp_id " +
                " AND at_cub_details.grp_id = at_group.grp_id " +
                " AND at_cub_details.cd_id = at_section_details.cd_id " +
                " AND at_section_details.sd_start_date = (SELECT MIN(section.sd_start_date) " +
                                                            " FROM  at_section_details section " +
                                                            " WHERE section.cd_id = at_cub_details.cd_id " +
                                                                " AND section.sd_section = at_group.grp_section) " +

    " UNION ALL " +

    " SELECT at_cub_details.cd_id as cdID, at_cub_details.cd_surname as surname, at_cub_details.cd_first_name as firstName," +
        " null as dob, null as archived, null as scoutNo, " +
        " null as grpName, " +
        " null as startDate, null as endDate, " +
        " SUM(hr_kilometres) as kilometres, SUM(hr_nights_under_canvas) as nights " +  
     " FROM at_account_group, at_group, at_section_details, at_cub_details, at_hiking_record " +
     " WHERE at_account_group.acc_id = ? " +
         " AND at_account_group.grp_id = at_cub_details.grp_id " +
         " AND at_cub_details.grp_id = at_group.grp_id " +
         " AND at_cub_details.cd_id = at_section_details.cd_id " +
         " AND at_section_details.sd_start_date = (SELECT MIN(section.sd_start_date) " +
                                                     " FROM  at_section_details section " +
                                                     " WHERE section.cd_id = at_cub_details.cd_id " +
                                                         " AND section.sd_section = at_group.grp_section) " +
         " AND at_cub_details.cd_id = at_hiking_record.cd_id " +
         " AND at_hiking_record.hr_start_date > (SELECT MIN(section2.sd_start_date) " +
                                                                 " FROM  at_section_details section2 " +
                                                                 " WHERE section2.cd_id = at_cub_details.cd_id " +
                                                                     " AND section2.sd_section = at_group.grp_section) " +
     " GROUP BY at_cub_details.cd_id " +

    " UNION ALL " +

    " SELECT at_cub_details.cd_id as cdID, at_cub_details.cd_surname as surname, at_cub_details.cd_first_name as firstName," +
        " null as dob, null as archived, null as scoutNo, " +
        " null as grpName, " +
        " null as startDate, null as endDate, " +
        " null as kilometres, SUM(event_nights_canvas) as nights " +
     " FROM at_account_group, at_group, at_section_details, at_cub_details, at_event " +
     " WHERE at_account_group.acc_id = ? " +
         " AND at_account_group.grp_id = at_cub_details.grp_id " +
         " AND at_cub_details.grp_id = at_group.grp_id " +
         " AND at_cub_details.cd_id = at_section_details.cd_id " +
         " AND at_section_details.sd_start_date = (SELECT MIN(section.sd_start_date) " +
                                                     " FROM  at_section_details section " +
                                                     " WHERE section.cd_id = at_cub_details.cd_id " +
                                                         " AND section.sd_section = at_group.grp_section) " +
         " AND at_cub_details.cd_id = at_event.cd_id " +
         " AND at_event.event_date_start > (SELECT MIN(section2.sd_start_date) " +
                                                                 " FROM  at_section_details section2 " +
                                                                 " WHERE section2.cd_id = at_cub_details.cd_id " +
                                                                     " AND section2.sd_section = at_group.grp_section) " +
        " GROUP BY at_cub_details.cd_id " +
     " ) a " +
      "GROUP BY surname, firstName;");
```

So I take the SELECT statement and paste it into MS Word and replace all " and + with space and ? with 30 (the value being passed from the client side) and then past the result into phpMyAdmin SQL and it runs and returns the expected results.

I am using Eclipse, GWT, java, mySQL.

So what is wrong with the prepared statement please?

The edited code I use in phpMyAdmin is:

```
SELECT cdID, surname, firstName, dob, archived, scoutNo, grpName, startDate, endDate, SUM(kilometres), SUM(nights) from (  
                SELECT at_cub_details.cd_id as cdID, at_cub_details.cd_surname as surname, at_cub_details.cd_first_name as firstName, 
                 at_cub_details.cd_dob as dob, at_cub_details.cd_archived as archived, at_cub_details.cd_scout_no as scoutNo,  
                 at_group.grp_name as grpName,  
                 at_section_details.sd_start_date as startDate, at_section_details.sd_end_date as endDate,  
                 null as kilometres, null as nights  
                 FROM at_cub_details, at_account_group, at_group, at_section_details   
                 WHERE at_account_group.acc_id = 30   
                     AND at_account_group.grp_id = at_cub_details.grp_id  
                     AND at_cub_details.grp_id = at_group.grp_id  
                     AND at_cub_details.cd_id = at_section_details.cd_id  
                     AND at_section_details.sd_start_date = (SELECT MIN(section.sd_start_date)  
                                                                 FROM  at_section_details section  
                                                                 WHERE section.cd_id = at_cub_details.cd_id  
                                                                     AND section.sd_section = at_group.grp_section)  

     UNION ALL  

     SELECT at_cub_details.cd_id as cdID, at_cub_details.cd_surname as surname, at_cub_details.cd_first_name as firstName, 
     null as dob, null as archived, null as scoutNo,  
     null as grpName,  
     null as startDate, null as endDate,  
     SUM(hr_kilometres) as kilometres, SUM(hr_nights_under_canvas) as nights    
          FROM at_account_group, at_group, at_section_details, at_cub_details, at_hiking_record  
          WHERE at_account_group.acc_id = 30  
              AND at_account_group.grp_id = at_cub_details.grp_id  
              AND at_cub_details.grp_id = at_group.grp_id  
              AND at_cub_details.cd_id = at_section_details.cd_id  
              AND at_section_details.sd_start_date = (SELECT MIN(section.sd_start_date)  
                                                          FROM  at_section_details section  
                                                          WHERE section.cd_id = at_cub_details.cd_id  
                                                              AND section.sd_section = at_group.grp_section)  
              AND at_cub_details.cd_id = at_hiking_record.cd_id  
              AND at_hiking_record.hr_start_date > (SELECT MIN(section2.sd_start_date)  
                                                                      FROM  at_section_details section2  
                                                                      WHERE section2.cd_id = at_cub_details.cd_id  
                                                                          AND section2.sd_section = at_group.grp_section)  
          GROUP BY at_cub_details.cd_id  

     UNION ALL  

     SELECT at_cub_details.cd_id as cdID, at_cub_details.cd_surname as surname, at_cub_details.cd_first_name as firstName, 
     null as dob, null as archived, null as scoutNo,  
     null as grpName,  
     null as startDate, null as endDate,  
     null as kilometres, SUM(event_nights_canvas) as nights  
          FROM at_account_group, at_group, at_section_details, at_cub_details, at_event  
          WHERE at_account_group.acc_id = 30  
              AND at_account_group.grp_id = at_cub_details.grp_id  
              AND at_cub_details.grp_id = at_group.grp_id  
              AND at_cub_details.cd_id = at_section_details.cd_id  
              AND at_section_details.sd_start_date = (SELECT MIN(section.sd_start_date)  
                                                          FROM  at_section_details section  
                                                          WHERE section.cd_id = at_cub_details.cd_id  
                                                              AND section.sd_section = at_group.grp_section)  
              AND at_cub_details.cd_id = at_event.cd_id  
              AND at_event.event_date_start > (SELECT MIN(section2.sd_start_date)  
                                                                      FROM  at_section_details section2  
                                                                      WHERE section2.cd_id = at_cub_details.cd_id  
                                                                          AND section2.sd_section = at_group.grp_section)  
             GROUP BY at_cub_details.cd_id  
              ) a  
              GROUP BY surname, firstName;
```

Comment: could it be the spelling: kilometres ? since it works in phpMyAdmin it must not be that, so can you also paste your phpMyAdmin query, that will give some clues ..

Comment: Thank you Saky, I have added the code I use, and works, in phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

In the first select statement change "SUM(kilometres), SUM(nights)" to "SUM(kilometres) as kilometres, SUM(nights) as nights".